# How to make a pill shaped button in android?

Tags: android, button, user-interface, android-drawable

I am not sure what to call this... pill shaped maybe. Googling for rounded corners turns up lots of posts of people wanting a rectangular button with rounded corners. This is a little different but more like 2 circles and a rectangle which I tried to draw it as.

I would like to make a button shaped something like the first image below but with text and an icon image in it by using an xml drawable background on an android :

I have tried this which looks ok but if the button length varies it does not scale and you end up with a rectangle and some other strange stuff.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="40dp" android:top="0dp" android:bottom="0dp">

        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="#666666"/>
            <size android:width="40dp" android:height="40dp"></size>

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item android:left="20dp" android:right="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#666666"/>
            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"></size>
        </shape>


    </item>

    <item android:right="40dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="#666666"/>
            <size android:width="40dp" android:height="40dp"></size>

        </shape>

    </item>


</layer-list>
```

[image]

I have tried to create my xml drawable like this also:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#666666" />

            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <size android:height="20dp" android:width="60dp"></size>
        </shape>
```

which looks like this:

[image]

I have looked at [this persons example](http://belencruz.com/2012/12/rounded-button-with-shadow-in-android/) but when I do what he does my results are not completely rounded at the corners. They are more like the second image above.

Comment: Have you tried messing with your radius values? That is what governs the look.

Comment: I know that you are wanting to use xml to create your button but I think the correct approach is to use a NinePatch image.

Comment: Can you post the entire xml for the second one

Comment: @twhite yes see the second block of xml.

Comment: @Larry I would rather not use a nine patch.

Comment: @Rod_algonquin that is the entire xml of the second one aside from <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: I am curious if your size values are messing up how it is ultimately drawn. I do not think you could have a 20dp radius with a 20dp height. I would think a 10dp radius for a 20dp height would be the max. I have not tested it just something I noticed.

Comment: @Larry Mckenzie The radius actually has no visible change on the results when its more than half of the height (or width if the width was smaller than height).

Answer (score 14):

You can try to save the following code to a drawable(e.g. pill_bg.xml):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="120dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#efefef" />

    <size
        android:width="300dp"
        android:height="120dp" />

</shape>
```

Take a look at size part and radius. Then apply the drawable to your view, for example:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/pill_bg" />
```

As you can see, your view can have different sizes, the background will be scaled.

Comment: how can I support this on multiple screen? What is 60dp on multiple screens? Remember I have we have to support multiple screens. I cannot handcode the size in dp. I have to support tablets, tvs, watches, tiny screens on mobile phones, blinding high res OLED screens on newer phones. T_T

Comment: It would be better to set the `<size>` attributes to a minimum height and width (such as 24dp), so the shape can be scaled up from that point. Much more difficult to size down to fit a view, but scaling up to fit is done automatically, provided it's used as a background to a TextView or Button.

Comment: setting a width and height to hard values is never a good idea

Answer (score 7):

This resizes correctly for any view background.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="1000dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Anything that contains 1000dp seems like a hack.  Why did you make it so high?

Comment: It's mildly hacky but it works. It's to prevent a flat edge if you apply this to the background of a large view.

Answer (score 6):

As of [v1.1.0-beta01 of the Material Components Android library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-beta01) you can use [MaterialButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton) and a [shapeAppearance](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/shape/#building-a-shape-appearance) style to easily define a pill button that doesn't require you to know the height of the button beforehand or rely on guessing a radius value high enough to go halfway down the side of the button.

Simply define a style like this:

```
<style name="PillShapeAppearance">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

and set it on your `MaterialButton` like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/PillShapeAppearance"
        />
```

The key that every other answer I've looked at leaves out is to set `cornerSize` with a percent value so that the fraction value it supports is properly applied.

Comment: I found this solution to be incredibly useful. It worked very well for me, I recommend it.

Answer (score -3):

Well you can make that button in any design program, also make one similar make it look like it  is pressed then you make a selector drawable and assign it to the button background. That´s the way i do pretty awesome buttons

Comment: I asked how to draw it in xml not how to do it in general. I know I could create a nine patch but why do that if I can do it in xml which is what I asked about.

Comment: Why? well one good reason is because you don't know how to make it on xml and maybe you are in a hurry. Another good reaseon is that you have a mor grained control on the drawable that you want to display, or maybe you want to create really good drawable to make an impact on user. Pick what ever it fits you